# function to dowload Table cell Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

so i have a table with objects and want to dowload each of it by clicking on dowload Button
[dowload Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucc79.png)

```
<wb-button
        name="submitButton"
        variant="primary"
        size="s"
        style="width:100%"
        (click)="downloadSdo(sdo)"
        i18n >Download</wb-button
      >
```

My question is How can the funtion in my file.ts should look like

```
 downloadSdo(sdo: SoftwareDataObject)
  {
    return sdo.id;
  }
```

Another option is to have the dowload button over my table and when click, the user should just choose which table he want to dowload. But how to make it. I am new to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you saw the picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify your object and then download it like this (example in JS):

```js
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(sdo)));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

if you just want to download the ID, then change the line with setAttribute() from `stringify(sdo)` to `stringify(sdo.id)`

Also check out this article: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: doesn't really help.